# 8051 Keil c51 Unable to properly use the INTERNAL EEPROM, on 89c52 or STC12C5A60S2

Tags: c, keil, 8051, eeprom, c51

Difficulty Reading/Writing Multiple Bytes from Internal EEPROM (STC12C5A60S2 / 89C52)
Body:

I'm encountering a persistent challenge in reading and writing multiple bytes from the internal EEPROM of an STC12C5A60S2 microcontroller,
both in a Proteus simulation and in a real-world application.

When I write and then read one byte, everything works fine.
But when I try to write 2 bytes, (one after the other), and then read them, the result is returns both readed bytes with the value of the last one that has been written.

Lets say that
When I write 0xABCD
It gets written 0xCDCD

To provide context, I've simulated the STC12C5A60S2 using an 89c02 as a substitute due to the unavailability of the exact model in Proteus.

- IDE : Using uVision Keil C51
- Simulation : Proteus 8  (MCU 89C52)
- Real life: Custom board (MCU STC12C5A60S2)

I've explored three different approaches:

**Attempt 0:  Using Demo Code from Datasheet:**
I initially attempted to implement the code provided in the datasheet (https://www.stcmicro.com/datasheet/STC12C5A60S2-en.pdf) on page 374.
Exact copy the code provided by the producer, it is so long so i wont post it here, see the repo, I added some prints to ease the interpretation.
It is supposed a bunch of demo operations
It doesnt work how it should.

[Attempt 0: See the full simulable repo here.](https://github.com/iorp/c51-problem-internal_eeprom_problem_try_0_from_datasheet/)

**Attempt 1: Using Demo Code from Datasheet Simplified Read/Write for Single and Multiple Bytes:**
I then simplified the code to read and write one byte, as well as two bytes. Surprisingly, everything works fine when performing single-byte operations.
However, when attempting consecutive read and write operations for multiple bytes, both bytes end up with the value of the last one.

```
 
 /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* --- STC MCU International Limited ----------------------------------*/
/* --- STC 1T Series MCU ISP/IAP/EEPROM Demo ----------------*/
/* If you want to use the program or the program referenced in the */
/* article, please specify in which data and procedures from STC */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "reg51.h"
#include "intrins.h"
#include "uart.h"

typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned int WORD;
/*Declare SFR associated with the IAP */
sfr IAP_DATA = 0xC2; //Flash data register
sfr IAP_ADDRH = 0xC3; //Flash address HIGH
sfr IAP_ADDRL = 0xC4; //Flash address LOW
sfr IAP_CMD = 0xC5; //Flash command register
sfr IAP_TRIG = 0xC6; //Flash command trigger
sfr IAP_CONTR = 0xC7; //Flash control register
/*Define ISP/IAP/EEPROM command*/
#define CMD_IDLE 0 //Stand-By
#define CMD_READ 1 //Byte-Read
#define CMD_PROGRAM 2 //Byte-Program
#define CMD_ERASE 3 //Sector-Erase
/*Define ISP/IAP/EEPROM operation const for IAP_CONTR*/
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x80 //if SYSCLK<30MHz
  #define ENABLE_IAP 0x81 //if SYSCLK<24MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x82 //if SYSCLK<20MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x83 //if SYSCLK<12MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x84 //if SYSCLK<6MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x85 //if SYSCLK<3MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x86 //if SYSCLK<2MHz
//#define ENABLE_IAP 0x87 //if SYSCLK<1MHz
//Start address for STC12C5A60S2 EEPROM
#define IAP_ADDRESS 0x0000 
void Delay(BYTE n);
void IapIdle();
BYTE IapReadByte(WORD addr);
void IapProgramByte(WORD addr, BYTE dat);
void IapEraseSector(WORD addr);
void main()
{
 
 UART_init(9600);
 

 UART_printStr("System Reset OK\r");
 Delay(10); //Delay (this is an eternal test delay )


 

/*
>>> WORKS FINE! Writing and reading a single byte 

// Write a byte
 UART_printStr("Writing 0xAB\r");
  IapProgramByte(0, (BYTE)0xAB); // Write byte 
  Delay(10); //Delay  

  // Read and print a byte
 UART_printStr("Readed \r");
 UART_printHex( IapReadByte(0),1);
 UART_printStr("\r");
   
*/



/*
>>>  WORKS NOT  FINE! Writing and reading a multiple bytes 
*/
  
// Write one byte
 UART_printStr("Writing 0xAB\r");
  IapProgramByte(0, (BYTE)0xAB); // Write byte 
  Delay(10); //Delay  
  // Write other byte
   UART_printStr("Writing 0xCD\r");
  IapProgramByte(1, (BYTE)0xCD); // Write byte 
  Delay(10); //Delay   

  // Read and print one byte
 UART_printStr("Readed \r");
 UART_printHex( IapReadByte(0),1);
 UART_printStr("\r");
  
    // Read and print the other byte
 UART_printStr("Readed \r");
 UART_printHex( IapReadByte(1),1);
 UART_printStr("\r");

 

 while (1);
}
/*----------------------------
Software delay function
----------------------------*/ 
void Delay(BYTE n)
{
 WORD x;
 while (n--)
 {
 x = 0;
 while (++x);
 }
}
/*----------------------------
Disable ISP/IAP/EEPROM function
Make MCU in a safe state
----------------------------*/
void IapIdle()
{
 IAP_CONTR = 0; //Close IAP function
 IAP_CMD = 0; //Clear command to standby
 IAP_TRIG = 0; //Clear trigger register
 IAP_ADDRH = 0x80; //Data ptr point to non-EEPROM area
 IAP_ADDRL = 0; //Clear IAP address to prevent misuse
}
/*----------------------------
Read one byte from ISP/IAP/EEPROM area
Input: addr (ISP/IAP/EEPROM address)
Output:Flash data
----------------------------*/
BYTE IapReadByte(WORD addr)
{
 BYTE dat; //Data buffer
 IAP_CONTR = ENABLE_IAP; //Open IAP function, and set wait time
 IAP_CMD = CMD_READ; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM READ command
 IAP_ADDRL = addr; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address low
 IAP_ADDRH = addr >> 8; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address high
 IAP_TRIG = 0x5a; //Send trigger command1 (0x5a)
 IAP_TRIG = 0xa5; //Send trigger command2 (0xa5)
 _nop_(); //MCU will hold here until ISP/IAP/EEPROM
 //operation complete
 dat = IAP_DATA; //Read ISP/IAP/EEPROM data
 IapIdle(); //Close ISP/IAP/EEPROM function
 return dat; //Return Flash data
}
 
/*----------------------------
Program one byte to ISP/IAP/EEPROM area
Input: addr (ISP/IAP/EEPROM address)
 dat (ISP/IAP/EEPROM data)
Output:-
----------------------------*/
void IapProgramByte(WORD addr, BYTE dat)
{
 IAP_CONTR = ENABLE_IAP; //Open IAP function, and set wait time
 IAP_CMD = CMD_PROGRAM; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM PROGRAM command
 IAP_ADDRL = addr; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address low
 IAP_ADDRH = addr >> 8; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address high
 IAP_DATA = dat; //Write ISP/IAP/EEPROM data
 IAP_TRIG = 0x5a; //Send trigger command1 (0x5a)
 IAP_TRIG = 0xa5; //Send trigger command2 (0xa5)
 _nop_(); //MCU will hold here until ISP/IAP/EEPROM
 //operation complete
 IapIdle();
}
/*----------------------------
Erase one sector area
Input: addr (ISP/IAP/EEPROM address)
Output:-
----------------------------*/
void IapEraseSector(WORD addr)
{
 IAP_CONTR = ENABLE_IAP; //Open IAP function, and set wait time
 IAP_CMD = CMD_ERASE; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM ERASE command
 IAP_ADDRL = addr; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address low
 IAP_ADDRH = addr >> 8; //Set ISP/IAP/EEPROM address high
 IAP_TRIG = 0x5a; //Send trigger command1 (0x5a)
 IAP_TRIG = 0xa5; //Send trigger command2 (0xa5)
 _nop_(); //MCU will hold here until ISP/IAP/EEPROM
 //operation complete
 IapIdle();
}
```

[Attempt 1: See the full simulable repo here.](https://github.com/iorp/c51-problem-internal_eeprom_problem_try_1_from_datasheet_simplified/)

**Attempt 2: Adapted Code from Other Sources:**
As a third approach, I adapted code snippets from various sources to address the issue. While this approach shows promise,
I'm still encountering the same problem of values not persisting across multiple-byte operations.

```
#include "header/stc12.h"
#include <intrins.h>
#include "uart.h"
 
 
 
// Define the EEPROM base address
#define EEPROM_BASE_ADDRESS 0x0000

// Function to write a byte to EEPROM
void EEPROM_writeByte(unsigned int address, unsigned char byteToWrite) {
    EA = 0; // Disable interrupts during write operation
    IAP_CONTR = 0x82; // Enable IAP and set programming time

    IAP_DATA = byteToWrite; // Load data to be written
    IAP_ADDRH = (address >> 8) & 0xFF; // Load high byte of address
    IAP_ADDRL = address & 0xFF; // Load low byte of address

    IAP_CMD = 0x02; // Command to erase and write one byte
    IAP_TRIG = 0x5A; // Trigger IAP
   _nop_();// Wait for IAP to complete

    EA = 1; // Re-enable interrupts
}

// Function to read a byte from EEPROM
unsigned char EEPROM_readByte(unsigned int address) {
    unsigned char readData;

    EA = 0; // Disable interrupts during read operation
    IAP_CONTR = 0x80; // Enable IAP

    IAP_ADDRH = (address >> 8) & 0xFF; // Load high byte of address
    IAP_ADDRL = address & 0xFF; // Load low byte of address

    IAP_CMD = 0x01; // Command to read one byte
    IAP_TRIG = 0x5A; // Trigger IAP

     
        _nop_();// Wait for IAP to complete
     

    readData = IAP_DATA; // Read the data from EEPROM

    EA = 1; // Re-enable interrupts

    return readData;
}


 
void main() {
     

    unsigned char byteToWrite = 0xAA;
    
    UART_init(9600);
    
    UART_printStr("Hello, this is working with one byte ... \r"); 
    // Write a byte to EEPROM
    EEPROM_writeByte(0, 0xAA); 
    // Read the byte from EEPROM 
    UART_printHex(EEPROM_readByte(0),1);// Print readed

 


    
        UART_printStr("\r... but not with 2 \r"); 
    // Write a byte to EEPROM
    EEPROM_writeByte(1, 0xBB); 
        _nop_(); // no matter how long I wait here 
    EEPROM_writeByte(2, 0xCC); 
    // Read the byte from EEPROM 
    UART_printHex(EEPROM_readByte(1),1);// Print readed
        _nop_(); // no matter how long I wait here
    UART_printHex(EEPROM_readByte(2),1);// Print readed
    

    while(1) {
        // Main loop, do nothing
    }
}
```

[Attempt 2: See the full simulable repo here.](https://github.com/iorp/c51-problem-internal_eeprom_problem_try_2)

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue, especially considering it persists in both simulation and real-world applications. If there are alternative approaches or corrections to the code, I'm open to exploring them. Thank you for your assistance!

I have attempted to run, among others, the examples shown on the post, available on github.
I also have attempthed almost eternal delays between operations.
Also a lot of annoying chatGPT.

Comment: Here's something to try: Write 01, 02, ..., FF to 256 consecutive bytes. Then read them all back. What is the pattern of the bytes read?

Comment: Hi , thanks for the idea, unfortunately I have tried that. And the value is always the last byte inserted. You can see it on the first attempt. I think it might be some register, but I can't find any info in the datasheet.

Comment: I don't see where you write *more than two* consecutive bytes in any of these test programs?  What I'm wondering is if maybe you need to be writing larger chunks than one byte, somehow, and if that'd show up as, e.g. writing 01 02 03 04 05 06 ... and getting back 02 02 04 04 06 06 ... or something like that.

Comment: The example 1 does it with 512 , and the 2 and 3 with 2 consecutive bytes. Did you run any?

Comment: Oh, you mean "attempt 0." I see now. No, I didn't run it, I do not have a suitable environment nor enough time right now to set one up. I'm afraid I am out of ideas.

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question to provide links to the data sheets of the STC12C5A60S2 and the 89C52? If you use the AT89C52, it does not work like the STC12C5A60S2!

Comment: Your attempt 2 does not process the `IAP_TRIG` correctly. It needs to receive two bytes of 0x5A and 0xA5, respectively.